# AWS EC2 Instance and sending email via gmail SMTP 587

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp

I have a very interesting situation. My App which is deployed on EC2 instance sends e-mail notifications to users by Gmail SMTP on port 587. 
Everything works smooth and fast when my EC2 instance has attached public IP or EIP but when I disassociate public IP my app has huge problems with sending e-mails. 
Ultimately for 10 attempts, only 2 sometimes 3 finish successfully (with big delay). When I was analyzing logs on live, during sending process without public ip I noticed evidently that App had a huge communication problems.

I'm pretty sure that my security layers accept all necessary inbound and outbound connections (without that even attaching public IP wouldn't work).

I was trying to dig in what can cause the problem and I found this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/outgoing-connections-on-port-25-587-143-blocked-over-ipv6 but it didn't solve my problem.

Maybe anyone is familiar with this issue?

Comment: If you have neither a public IP nor an EIP, then how are you getting to the Internet at all?  It should fail 100%.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot EC2 instance is deployed in public subnet and at the front I have Network Load Balancer which is responsible for managing internal traffic flow.

Comment: Network Load Balancer only handles connections where your instance is the target -- not the source.  You need an outbound path for IPv4 traffic -- public/elastic IP if on a public subnet, or NAT device if on a private subnet.  Or perhaps an IPv6 route... but I would expect problems without IPv4 connectivity.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks very much it sounds very sensible. I'll try to route traffic using bastion host and I'll get back here when I will succeed.

Comment: Note that there is no requirement that instances and their balancers be in the same subnet, and no performance penalty if they are not.  Instances without public IPs should not be in a public subnet, they should be in a private subnet with a NAT Gateway providing them with the ability to initiate outbound traffic toward the Internet.

Comment: ok, I try all you sugesttions asap. Many thanks again for help

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Hi unfortunately it doesn't work. I provisioned NAT Gateway at public subnet and private subnet has it in the route table. After these changes I my SPA located at S3 bucket lost conenction with app api which is located in private subnet behind network load balancer

Comment: the version (internal, internet-facing) load balance has any matter in this case? I use currently internet-facing.

Comment: definitely it's inbound connection is blocked. NLB behave very strange in my particular case...

Comment: No, the type of balancer doesn't matter.  I can't speculate what detail you might have overlooked but this should have worked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when I would use ELB or ALB it may be working but in case of NLB traffic flow behave very strange.

Comment: Agreed, but NLB has a deep integration into the network infrastructure that should continue to allow this to work even in that case.